# Как сделать задержку между написание символов на Python

Tags: python

Вот я например написал `print("hello world", ...)` и после запятой на месте точек я помню раньше писал какой-то слово и у меня выводилось то что в `print` не сразу, а с задержкой, типо я писал там слово, писал равно и после равно число в секундах какая будет задержка у написания после каждого символа, при том оно выводилось не на новую строку каждый раз, а всё писалось в одну, и это всё без модулей time и sleep было. ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

Comment: Нет такого ключевого слова в функции `print()` - существуют только 4 такие: `sep=`, `end=`, `file=` и `flush=`. Может быт в каком то другом языке программирования?

Comment: может быть, но просто я помню как на visual studio code я как где-то это узнал сразу начал пользоваться, а потом перестал и забыл, но спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без использования `sleep` никак не получится. Возможно ты тогда использовал какую-ту библиотеку для этого, но я лично не знаю ничего подобного. Я написал функцию которая выполняет твою задачу:

```
import time

def print_with_delay(word, delay):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    for char in word:
        while time.perf_counter() - start_time < delay:
            pass  # just loop until the delay time has passed
        print(char, end='', flush=True)
        start_time = time.perf_counter()

print_with_delay('Hello, World!', 1.0)  # prints each character with a delay of 1 second
```

Comment: ой спасибо большое